# javascript canvasjs Get data points dynamically from file.txt

Tags: canvasjs

Objective:

I want to get data from file.txt thats is saved local in /var/www/html/file.txt and use it for the doughnut chart on my webpage dynamically on a interval of 2 seconds

file.txt only has one entry and  looks like:

```
34
```

the javascript i have tried:

```
$.get("file.txt", function(data) {
var x = 0;
var allLines = data.split('\n');
if(allLines.length > 0) {
    for(var i=0; i< allLines.length; i++) {
        dataPoints.push({y: parseInt(allLines[i])});
        x += .25;
    }
}
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
    title :{
        text: "Chart using Text File Data"
    },
    data: [{
        type: "doughnut",
        dataPoints : dataPoints,
    }]
});
chart.render();
});
}
```

Entire html looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Chart using txtfile Data</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script            /jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$.get("graph.txt", function(data) {
var xVal = 0;
var allLines = data.split('\n');
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
    title :{
        text: "Chart using Text File Data"
    },
    data: [{
        type: "line",
        dataPoints : [function()
        {
        if(allLines.length > 0) {
           for(var i=0; i< allLines.length; i++) {
           xVal +=.25;
           dataPoints.push({x : xVal, y: parseInt(allLines[i])});
    }
}
}]
    }]
});
chart.render();
},'text');
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like this may work for you. You may have to use Firefox as Chrome doesn't like cross origin requests

First, dataPoints was undefined, I moved the code into a function inside dataPoints. I changed your variable name from x to xVal. Added the 'text' word so the $get knows what format it's reading and also there was an extra bracket it seemed. Give this a try.

```
    $.get("graph.txt", function(data) {
var xVal = 0;
var allLines = data.split('\n');
var dps = [];

for(var i=0; i< allLines.length; i++) {
   xVal +=.25;
   dps.push({x : xVal, y: Number(allLines[i])});
}

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
    title :{
        text: "Chart using Text File Data"
    },
    data: [{
        type: "line",
        dataPoints : dps
    }]
});
chart.render();
},'text');
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I must not understand something that code producdes a empty line graph i have added the entire html to the original post.

Comment: I changed the code a little bit to push the values first to an array, then add that array to the dataPoints. The other issue was I had to convert the allLines[i] object to number. I tested it and the line now displays

Comment: It works perfect Thank you very much. It was also a learning experience because i can see how to soled the issues.